# How to make sure the docker container has desired network interfaces

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

When I run ifconfig command on host machine(ubuntu) I see following interfaces

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:af:2d:7b:4e
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:afff:fe2d:7b4e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17372371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18910860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3877362521 (3.8 GB)  TX bytes:5648219155 (5.6 GB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:bd:6d:6c
          inet addr:9.113.140.176  Bcast:9.113.140.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:febd:6d6c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22690545 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4168167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5364157575 (5.3 GB)  TX bytes:398826434 (398.8 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:a3:7f:17
          inet addr:9.113.140.166  Bcast:9.113.140.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::11ff:7a9c:83ed:f11f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16962121 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1214246465 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:515223 (515.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:605048269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:605048269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:137424265344 (137.4 GB)  TX bytes:137424265344 (137.4 GB)
```

Where as when I check inside the container I find this

```
[AppConnect-Container@772840b42460 /]: ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:05
          inet addr:172.17.0.5  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12819 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:14565227 (14.5 MB)  TX bytes:10658766 (10.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:984571 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:984571 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:187746811 (187.7 MB)  TX bytes:187746811 (187.7 MB)
```

I want even the eth1 network interface to be available inside the container. Please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "be available"?  Not just "it shows up in `ifconfig`"; how would your application behave differently if it were there?

Answer (score 0):

Launch the container with `--net=host` option, and you'll have your host interfaces in the container.

Comment: --net=host option cannot be used as port will be binding to the host ip. So we cannot have multiple containers in same VM

Comment: You can also map your ports with `-p 8081:8080` to one container, `-p 8082:8080` to second container and so... With this, you don't have bind problems and conflicts with your 8080 port in host and all container in the VM are listening 8080.

Comment: Anyway, `--net=host` is the solution for your question, the solution for interface visibility problem. Port binding is another question.

Comment: When i tried --net=host and -p option i got this exception Address already in use (Bind failed) /9.113.140.176:8443

Comment: Maybe you're using 8443 in host, or in a second container. Please do port mapping `-p XXXX:8443`, being XXXX different for each container

Comment: if i am using --net=host then port mapping is not happening